# NSDateFormatter return (null) string when NSDate is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I use date formatter to get new string, but in some cases startDate can be nil.

```
resultDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:startDate]];
```

And then resultDate get `(null)` string (NSTaggedPointerString), but I expect to get just nil in case if formatter get nil as a parameter of date.

Comment: Why are you using `stringWithFormat:` the output of `stringFromDate:` is already a string ?

Comment: @rckoenes sorry it's copy paste, I used it for combine few strings, but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currently accepted answer isn't actually right.

`stringFromDate` does return `nil` when you pass it a `nil` date.

The reason your string is "(null)" is because `[NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", nil]` returns the string "(null)"

Comment: Not sure how I missed that...  Thanks, great answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `stringFromDate` instance method on `NSDateFormatter` is expecting a `(nonnull NSDate *)` and returns `NSString * _Nonnull`.

The `_Nonnull` keyword specifies that `stringFromDate` will always return an `NSString *` and never return nil, so on a nil date `stringFromDate` will return the string `"null"`.